# Alter certain column headers using list comprehension - python

Tags: python

I want to insert and underscore in each of the column headers within the df below, except for the first column. So `Time` should be left as is and each of the following columns should be inserted with an underscore.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({        
    'Time' : [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4],                               
    'X1' : [4,5,8,3,6,2,6,4,3.1,2,4,6,6,2,4,4],
    'Y1' : [-2,0,-2,0,0,4,-1,-2,-2,4,-3,2,-2,0,-2.5,4],     
    'X2' : [4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4],
    'Y2' : [-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2],                          
    })

df.columns = [f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}' for x in df.columns]

   T_i  X_1  Y_1  X_2  Y_2
0    1    4   -2    4   -2
1    1    5    0    4   -2
2    1    8   -2    4   -2
3    1    3    0    4   -2
4    1    6    0    4   -2
```

The following returns an error.

```
df.columns[:1] = [f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}' for x in df.columns[:1]]

raise TypeError("Index does not support mutable operations")

TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations
```

Intended Output

```
   Time  X_1  Y_1  X_2  Y_2
0     1    4   -2    4   -2
1     1    5    0    4   -2
2     1    8   -2    4   -2
3     1    3    0    4   -2
4     1    6    0    4   -2
```

Comment: The line after "the following returns an error" is missing an `]` is that the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working with `df.columns[:1]=` is probably not a good idea.

How about doing this

```
df.columns = [f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}' if num > 0 else x for num, x in enumerate(df.columns)]

or

df.columns = [f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}' if x != 'Time' else x for x in df.columns]
```